# Showing a white UINavigationBar for MFMailComposer with custom UINavigationBar themes in the app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have a simple app which is a `UITableViewController`. The app uses custom themes which applies a theme to the background and the `UINavigationBar`. From this view, I have a `UINavigationBarItem` (created in code) that brings up the email sheet with `MFMailComposerViewController`.

I'm finding some weird behaviour with the custom themed `UINavigationBar` and so I just want to remove the image and have a white UINavigationBar with black buttons (cancel, send, title).

I have the code below:

```
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
{
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mailer setSubject:@"PDF"];
    [mailer addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:fileName];
    NSString *emailBody = @"Please find attached PDF";
    [mailer setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

    [self presentViewController:mailer animated:YES completion:^{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
        mailer.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blackColor]};
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:nil forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [[mailer navigationBar] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

    }];
}
```

So I am actually removing the image there. The issue is that it works, but it doesn't actually make the buttons black as they should be. Also, in some instances, there are occurrences where the custom themed `UINavigationBar` image shows through. I want this to never happen.

I even went as far as creating a new class which was a subclass of `MFMailComposer` and setting the "theme" of the `UINavigationBar` to be a white created bar, but that still brought about the images sometimes.

What I want is to ensure the `UINavigationBar` never shows an image and always has black buttons for the Cancel, Title and Send.

Any thoughts would be really appreciated.

**Update**

With removing the `setBarTintColor` and `setTintColor` code above, I have noticed that the first time I invoke the `MFMailComposeViewController`, the theme is there in the `UINavigationBar`, but if I close that view, and re-open it, then the image is removed and the `UINavigationBar` is white. How can I get this to show up as white always, without a theme? I have also removed the code that removes the images to outside of the completion block, but that didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fill UINavigationBar with color you can use **backgroundImage** property with blank shadow image:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[self imageWithColor:[UIColor whiteColor]] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
```

**-imageWithColor** is an additional method for creating UIImage with selected color:

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithColor:(UIColor *)color {
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [color CGColor]);
CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return image; 
}
```

Then set black text color and black status bar so it will be visible:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleDefault];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blackColor]}];
```

And don't forget that these properties will be applied to every navigation bar.
Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Dear @Artem - thanks so much for the answer here and this is really great! This makes a lot of sense and that's really helpful. There is still an issue though, that the first time I invoke this MFMail, the theme is shown, but if I launch it again, it's then appropriately white (as per my update). I've put in an NSLog and 1) if this code is in the completion block, it gets run after a 2 second gap. If I take it out of the completion block, it still has a 2 second gap, which is I guess why the first time it's run, the theme is there, but the second time (it's loaded), it's white...

Comment: I've just created a custom class of MFMailComposeViewController and called that from the class above.. The viewWillAppear loads before the presentViewController in the block, but still, the first time it loads, it shows the theme rather than the white. The second time always works

Comment: Sorry for another message - I realised I was initiating the theme from somewhere else, which was why it was getting dragged in the first time. Following your code and removing mine helped me achieve this. Thanks so much for your work on this - highly appreciated!